# Create and show a jRadioButton when I push a button

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm writing a code that, when I push a jButton, create and show in a jPannel a jRadioButton. In NetBeans I have writted, in the action method of the jButton, this part of code:

```
javax.swing.JRadioButton birdButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton("ciao");
birdButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
birdButton.setActionCommand("ciao");
birdButton.setSelected(true);
jPanel1.add(birdButton);
jPanel1.revalidate();
jPanel1.repaint();
```

but, when I push the button the jRadioButton doesn't appear. The jPanel1 there is. What's the trouble? Thanks.

Comment: what is the layout of panel?did you call `revalidate() ` and  `repaint() `methods

Comment: I have edited the code and I have inserted jPanel1.revalidate() and jPanel1.repaint() but never again.

Comment: Can we please see the JButton code? Specifically the action listener or other method you're using for the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you drag and drop `jpanel` to `jframe` in netbeans from visual component section,they set your panel layout to somelayout for example `group layout`
so when you add component you will not see it probably because there is different way to add components to different layout .not just `.add()` .you should add appropriate layout according to your expected design.

for example if you set layout to `flowlayout` you will see the `jradiobuton` as you expect.

this is how you can set layout to a component in netbean ide.

[image]